# How to ensure that a DIV comes below the navbar?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using Materialize to create a navbar like the code below shows. After that, I render a div element to hold my application but the topmost part of it gets hidden by NAV element.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="nav-extended deep-purple">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      ...
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="application right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li>...</li>
        ...
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="application">Shazoo</div>
```

My current workaround is to simply add a top margin to the DIV named *application* but it's hardly something I want to see in a printed book as a best practice. I'm guessing there's a specific hack for Materialize that I haven't found. The documentation seems a bit Spartan on the website.

Comment: You are fond of divs... there is no need for (or at least there shouldn't be any need for) the outermost div (the `class="navbar-fixed"`) nor the inner div (the `class="nav-wrapper"`) - `<nav>` is perfectly fine on its own, and the `<ul>` inside it as well.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Actually he does need `class="navbar-fixed"` if he wants the navbar to stay fixed to the top or whatever position he wants the div to stay at.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I was under the impression that I need the outermost div to keep the class fixing the navbar. It seems not to behave correctly without it. But you're right that I'm a big fan of divs. I like diving because it creates areas of separation for better control.

Comment: If he needs the `<div>` for the `navbar-fixed`, there is something very wrong with his CSS. He has multiple classes on the `<nav>`-element already, he should be able to either move the `navbar-fixed`-class to the `<nav>`-element itself, or just add the CSS from `navbar-fixed` to one of the classes already on the `<nav>`-element. I'm suspecting some stupid framework-css, though (materialize, I guess).

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Are you *guessing*? Check the tag, mate, hehe. Good shot, there. Materialize wasn't my decision. It was made by the head of the other team, I'm starting to learn it as we speak. Hence the somewhat dumb questions, possibly. I'd prefer Bootstrap but I was voiced down. :)

Comment: Urgh. Bootstrap is equally idiotic.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie That's quite categorical statement. What framework would you prefer? Or are you suggesting going bare?

Comment: All CSS frameworks are equally crappy. They overuse classes, have almost no inheritance, and makes you fill and bloat the HTML with hundreds of classes which both makes the code horrible to debug, and serves no real purpose than preventing people from learning either HTML or CSS. Yes, I'm "going bare". I can mostly guarantee you that for most pages (as close to "all" as I'm willing to state), it's a better method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid adding the margin or an extra div, just add top padding to your body like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: ABCpx;
}
```

Where **ABCpx** is the height of your fixed navbar.

Comment: The navbar isn't fixed in height. It's fixed with respect to scrolling of the page, so it always stays at the top.

Comment: @Konrad Yes, that's what I meant by fixed too. The above solution makes sure that no content is hidden underneath the navbar unless you start scrolling down which would obviously push content off the screen irrespective of whether a fixed-position navbar is there or not.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain my issue well enough. What would be the number to offset from the top? The navbar can be 50px tall but then, if a user clicks on a menu, a submenu will add to the navbar and it's then 80px tall.

Comment: Ok I'm confused. So you want the content to get pushed down once a sub-menu is clicked and expanded or?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The topmost line of the content should be just below the bottom edge of the navbar. If it grows vertically, the content should be pushed too.

Comment: @Konrad Oh ok. The dropdown menu div's position needs to be toggled for that. Can you please replicate what you have so far in jsfiddle?

Comment: It's in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40704438/1525840) and points out to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/e8ykLL7q/). The *home* menu will fold in the lower part, eventually. And there might be additional sub-submenus in the future too. If JS reaction is the only approach, I know how to do it. I was just hoping to a neat and simple workaround based on, well... anything but JS.

Answer (score 1):

If the navbar is positioned using "fixed" then I adding margin-top to the following div would, in my opinion, be the correct method, or else adding padding.

Comment: @Andrew Lyndem is correct if you are trying to avoid another div. But given you are likely to have that div containing your content anyway, I guess it's six of one and half a dozen of the other.

Comment: Oh, I loved the expression. In Sweden we say it's *cutting or chopping*, hehe. Also, what if the darn navbar fluctuates in height? I have some extra submenus that can be displayed.